# WebLogic 12c, how to set console cookie name with WLST

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

In the admin console, I can set the admin console cookie name under *Domain -> Configuration -> General -> Advanced -> Console Cookie Name*

How do I set the values using WLST in **offline** mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample script to update the cookie domain :

```
readDomain(<FULL PATH TO YOUR DOMAIN>)
create('NO_NAME_0','AdminConsole')
cd ('AdminConsole')
cd ('NO_NAME_0')
set('CookieName','<NEW COOKIE NAME>>')
updateDomain()
closeDomain()
```

Comment: This works. But why is it I have to use `create` first? Referring to the WLST documentation, where is this explained?

Comment: All mbeans are not always present after the domain creation. You have to check if it exists or not and then create it if needed.

Comment: So am I right, as in the offline mode we are actually working with configuration files and not runtime MBeans, the configuration files for certain MBean's doesn't exist if the server is not started up once. And during runtime, these MBean's may persist their state in the configuration files if necessary.

Comment: When you are updating the configuration you are always working on configuration mbeans, whether you are in online or offline mode. Runtime mbeans do not carry any configuration information that you can update.